# Using variables of one class in another class (both defined from abstract classes)

Tags: c++

I am using two abstract Classes as `Game` and `Player` as interfaces for a game 
(lets call it XX):

```
class Game --> class XXGame: public Game
class Player --> class XXPlayer: public Player
```

and I am controlling the game in another class named:

```
class GameControl
```

There is a member function in `XXGame` (overloaded version of the one which is in its interface `Game`) as:

```
1-   int XXGame::play(char* bet, int amount);
```

which I call it in `GameControl.cpp` to give me the result of one round of game.
but I also need to use that member function in a member function of `XXPlayer` as:

```
2-    bool XXPlayer::play(int numberOfTimes);
```

as you can see there is just `int numberOfTimes` as the parameter of function(2).
However I need to call function (1) in function (2). I have created a pointer to `Game` in class `XXPlayer` as:

```
Game* _gamep;
```

but still I don't know how can I access the parameters in function (1) used in `GameControl` and use them in function(2) Since I am kind of limited with the abstract classes.
Actually using function (1) and its parameters is really crucial for function(2) and I shouldn't change the structure of the interfaces of course.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to re-consider your design if you are needing to do something wacky like that. Why have you defined your interfaces in such a limiting way? If the two play functions are so interdependent why are they separate.

Comment: As I said I shouldn't change the structure of the interfaces.

Comment: why do you have to keep the interfaces the same?

Comment: because it is a project!

Answer (score 0):

Can `XXPlayer` play a game of `WWGame`?

No? Then the pointer `_gamep` should have been of type `XXGame` in the first place. You may perform a dynamic cast from `Game` to `XXGame` when it is assigned (note that this may fail if it wasn't an `XXGame` instance) and the `XXPlayer` can internally access the game type specific extended interface of the corresponding game class.

As long as an outsider doesn't know that `XXPlayer` exists, as a specialisation, the abstract `Player` interface fully fulfills it's role of hiding the details. Note that you should then also keep `XXPlayer` and `XXGame` hidden by the use of a factory pattern, so that the calling code only knows them as abstract `Game` and `Player`.